# microsoft.dotnet-openapi : Generate yaml from command line

Tags: .net-6.0, openapi.net

I have an Azure Function v4 .net 6 with an http trigger. I have some OpenAi attributes and would like to generate the yaml file to use it in pipeline.

From documetation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?view=aspnetcore-7.0) I don't see such is possible.

My idea would be to generate the open api yaml file after build, similar to this (https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/generate-aspnet-core-openapi-spec-at-build-time).